# Performance implications of saving an iterated map in a single database table

Tags: database, haskell, sqlite

I have a Haskell type that look essentially like this:

```
data Thing = Map Int (Map Int (DataInside Int Int Int))
```

(It is not a `Map (Int, Int) (DataInside Int Int Int)` because data of type `Map Int (DataInside Int Int Int)` which is associated to a first key of type `Int` is used quite often.)

An inhabitant of this type needs to be persistently stored. So far it was being written to files using `Serialize` instances and [cereal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal). (However, the data is kept in memory while the program is running, so the overhead of reading or writing a file occurs only when the program starts or exits.)

I am considering storing this data in a SQLite database instead (and not in memory anymore). I was thinking of having a table with five columns (two for keys, so with a uniqueness constraint, and three for values) and accessing the values with pairs of keys.

I am wondering what the performance implication of this would be. For example, how would looking up an entry with keys `i` and `j` compare to computing `(M.! j) . (M ! i)` (which should take around `O(log n + log m)` where n is the number of first keys and m is the maximum number of second keys for a first key)? How would it perform while updating an entry with given keys?

As for the size of the data set, there are currently tens of different first keys, and tens of different second keys for each first key, but the data set is expected to grow (but there will always be roughly as many second key values for each first key value as there are first key values).

Comment: You should have the same asymptotic performance: log n + log m for query and for updating existing entries. I don't know btrees well enough to say for sure, but I imagine the same answer applies for adding new entries. Of course the constant factor will be different, and probably larger, than an in-memory map, but the advantage is you don't need to keep everything in memory.

Comment: Side note: `IntMap` is *almost always* better than `Map Int`.